# Using setOnClickListener on RecyclerView Fragment to move to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

I want to (1) pass the position variable and (2) open a new activity when an item is clicked.

I found that I need to create `Activity` variable in order to use `Intent`, and I also found that I can use `putExtra` to pass the position variable.

Although the below code works for regular_activity.java, it does not work for fragment.java. It completely shuts down the app when I open this fragment.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent int_detail = new Intent(activity, bottom_nav_search_details.class);
    int_detail.putExtra("position", position);
    activity.startActivity(int_detail); }
```

Just in case anyone finds useful, here is longer lines of codes. When I remove the above part (Intent part), everything works--Log successfully shows different positions when I click different items.

```
private Activity activity;
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final ExampleItem currentItem = exampleList.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
    holder.textView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());

    holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clicked " + position);
            Intent int_detail = new Intent(activity, bottom_nav_search_details.class);
            int_detail.putExtra("position", position);
            activity.startActivity(int_detail);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can get the host activity by getActivity() method in your Fragment

Comment: First thing is don't use listener in onBindViewHolder() Method. Register a listener inside Viewholder class and create an interface that will communicate with you activity or fragment then call the method that you will create in interface and pass getAdapterPosition() . if you feel itx helped you Rate my comment thanks For more Check this https://medium.com/hackernoon/android-recyclerview-onitemclicklistener-getadapterposition-a-better-way-3c789baab4db

Comment: @hosseinAmini getActivity() is red-colored. It seems it does not work. Would you please explain a proper way to use it?

Comment: You must get your host activity with getActivity()  in your fragment and then pass it to your adapter